# Event similar to focusin that only triggers once?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `focusin` on an element, but it triggers everytime the tab key is pressed on one of its child elements. Is there something like a `focusenter` that only triggers once (similar to that of `mouseenter`) when one of the child elements is focused?

I am trying to create a focus trap, so when focus enters the div via keyboard it focuses on the first item in the trap. Currently when I press <kbd>shift+tab</kbd> it focuses on the last item in the trap instead of the first item. When I enter the trap using only <kbd>shift</kbd> it focuses on the first item which is what I want.

```js
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('focusin', () => {
  console.log('here');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.item:focus-visible {
  outline: red solid 2px;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="" class="item">Item A</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Item B</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Item C</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Slev7n That doesn't do anything...

Comment: try passing **e** to the callback and **if(e.target == e.currentTarget){** in your function. Target will get the element that triggered the event and currentTarget is the element that the handler is attached to. If they aren't equal you don't want to do anything.

Comment: the currentTarget never triggers the event, so it always returns false

Comment: What are you trying to actually accomplish? I'm unable to actually get the parent div to actually get focused on.

Comment: I am trying to create a focus trap, so when focus enters the div it focuses on the first item in the trap. Currently when I press shift+tab it focuses on the last item in the trap instead of the first item. When I enter the trap using only shift it focuses on the first item which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve... But I'll assume you want to be able to focus only on the first element. And if the focus fell on it, it remained there until certain events. So you can add to all elements except the first `tabindex="-1"`. And if you want to prevent the focus from exiting when the keyboard is pressed, handle the `keydown` event. Something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('focusin', () => console.log('here'));
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('keydown', event => event.preventDefault())
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.item:focus-visible {
  outline: red solid 2px;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="" class="item">Item A</a>
  <a href="" tabindex="-1" class="item">Item B</a>
  <a href="" tabindex="-1" class="item">Item C</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke stopPropagation method on Event object and use capture

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('focusin', e => { 
//Logic goes here
e.stopPropagation(); 
}, true);
```